# Confusion around reference type variable in Swift

Tags: swift

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Home {
   var roomCount = 0
}
```

and I have this code snippet:

```
let home1 = Home()
let home2 = home1
let home3 = home1
home2 = home3 //error: cannot assign to value: 'home2' is a 'let' constant
home2 = Home() //error: cannot assign to value: 'home2' is a 'let' constant
```

I understand that for a let constant variable of reference type, you can't change what the variable references to, so the last line `home2 = Home()` makes sense to me because Home() creates a new instance in heap memory.

However, I am very confused around why `home2 = home3` also gives the same error. Since home2 and home3 they both reference to the same location in memory as home1 does, if I assign home3 to home2 it's technically not changing the reference to the memory location.

Comment: The *compiler* cannot know that `home2` and `home3` refer to the same instance.

Comment: I don't know enough of the technical details to give a proper answer, but I imagine this is just the compiler not being smart enough to realize nothing is actually changing. And I can't think of any situation where that would be useful behavior anyway.

Comment: @MartinR The compiler *could* know (though not in the general case), but it just doesn't make any sense to implement a rule: "Allow assignments that provable don't do anything" because... they don't do anything, provably...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is that you cannot assign to a property created by `let` (after it has been initialized). There are no exceptions. The compiler doesn't try to deduce that you're not actually changing the value. That would be a needless complication.

Answer (score 2):

A `let` constant cannot be reassigned at all. What you're assigning on the right hand side doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

let is for constant. No matter what assign to it... struct or class. Once you set value for it. After you can't override this... Memory management or another good things in this case does not matter!

It is compile stuff